# Why do my database results get displayed wrong

Tags: html, css, jsp

I have made a website and in a part of it, I want to output reviews that are stored on a database onto the page. This works and all the data is outputted, but every new entry is shifted to the right to the one above.

(see image below)

[This image shows the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mnpcw.png)

This is the code responsible to output the data:

```
 <%
    for(int i = (int) request.getAttribute("evalsize") - 1; i >= 0  ; i--)
    {
         Evaluation eval = (Evaluation) request.getAttribute("eval"+i);

        %>
    <div class="clearfix colelem" id="u18704"><!-- group -->



 <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u18698"><!-- group -->
      <!-- m_editable region-id="editable-static-tag-U18683-BP_infinity" template="show-hotel-proper.html" data-type="html" data-ice-options="disableImageResize,link,txtStyleTarget" -->
      <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u18683-4" data-muse-uid="U18683" data-muse-type="txt_frame" data-IBE-flags="txtStyleSrc"><!-- content -->
       <p><%= eval.getDateStart() %> - <%= eval.getDateEnd() %></p>
      </div>
      <!-- /m_editable -->
      <!-- m_editable region-id="editable-static-tag-U18686-BP_infinity" template="show-hotel-proper.html" data-type="html" data-ice-options="disableImageResize,link,txtStyleTarget" -->
      <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u18686-4" data-muse-uid="U18686" data-muse-type="txt_frame" data-IBE-flags="txtStyleSrc"><!-- content -->
       <p><%= eval.getMessage() %></p>
      </div>
      <!-- /m_editable -->
      <!-- m_editable region-id="editable-static-tag-U18689-BP_infinity" template="show-hotel-proper.html" data-type="html" data-ice-options="disableImageResize,link,txtStyleTarget" -->
      <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u18689-4" data-muse-uid="U18689" data-muse-type="txt_frame" data-IBE-flags="txtStyleSrc"><!-- content -->
       <p><%= eval.getStarsHotel()%></p>
      </div>
      <!-- /m_editable -->
      <!-- m_editable region-id="editable-static-tag-U18695-BP_infinity" template="show-hotel-proper.html" data-type="html" data-ice-options="disableImageResize,link,txtStyleTarget" -->
      <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u18695-4" data-muse-uid="U18695" data-muse-type="txt_frame" data-IBE-flags="txtStyleSrc"><!-- content -->
       <p><%= eval.getStarsActivities()%></p>
      </div>
      <!-- /m_editable -->
     </div>
     <div class="grpelem" id="u18701"><!-- simple frame --></div>
   <%}
    %> </div><%
}%>
```

I would appreciate it enormously, if someone could help me make sure each database result is below another.

Comment: It appears you're opening `<div class="clearfix colelem" id="u18704"><!-- group -->` in each iteration but you're not closing it. Either removing or closing it will likely fix your problem. Also note having duplicate ids in HTML is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your div elements. I think you have an extra one before this one

`<div class="grpelem" id="u18701"><!-- simple frame --></div>`